# Laravel Installer Running Out of Memory

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, cygwin

I have gotten composer to work on my laptop a while back, but I'm getting very stuck with getting it installed on my main computer. I have downloaded the latest version of Composer (1.10.8) and am using Cygwin on a Windows machine. The problem comes with running "composer global require laravel/installer" in that it keeps running out of memory. I have the PHP memory limit currently set at 8GB (which should be way more than enough) and yet it keeps saying it's running out of memory at the exact same place as it did with my memory limit at 128M, or 1024M, or 2048M! I have even tried the following command and got the following result:

```
$ php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer global require laravel/installer
Changed current directory to /home/User/.composer

PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 38273024) (tried to allocate 2102411 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 462

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 38273024) (tried to allocate 2102411 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 462
```

I am unsure what to do now because everywhere online keeps telling me to increase my memory limit but even with no memory limit, the output is the same. What should I do?

Comment: 38273024/1024/1024 = 36.5M. It's pretty low amount of RAM. Raise your limit and publish the error again. If the text is same - you forgot to restart the apache/php-pfm to perform the changes

Comment: ... or you edit the wrong place

Comment: @user1597430 as a good hint: Composer **never** uses Apache or FPM to perform its work. Never.

Comment: This seems to be a cygwin issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648665/cygwin-php-windows-10-out-of-memory

Answer (score 1):

Try to use x64 version of PHP.

To run composer using a local copy of PHP x64 you can do the following:

Download the zip file from here (VC15 x64 Thread Safe version): https://windows.php.net/download
Unzip the file
Copy php.ini-development and rename to php.ini
Uncomment the extension_dir = "ext" line and any other php extensions you will need (such as extension=gd2 or extension=openssl).
If any other PHP extensions are needed for the update then it will tell you while running the command.
Working command:

```
"C:\path\to\php-7.2.23-Win32-VC15-x64\php.exe" -d memory_limit=-1 "C:/path/to/composer.phar" update
```

Source: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/816/how-to-solve-composer-install-update-error-virtualalloc-failed-0x00000008

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. 1) The OP does use Cygwin, and probably doesn't want to install PHP again 2) `memory_limit=-1`  is already in use, but still a memory limit error is triggered